# Responsibility to new PhD students regarding bad environments

Tags: ethics, career-path

(Given that the question was put on hold, I try to ask the question differently. If it is still off-topic I vote for deletion. Still having trouble grasping the question.)

If you know that an institute/department/adviser is looking for new PhD students, but you also know that this institute/department/adviser is really bad for a scientific career (e.g., high attrition rates, few if any get tenure) — what do you do?

On the one hand, no one likes a snitch, people who complain are often seen as bitter and as lacking loyalty. And it might be a question of fit.

On the other hand, there is responsibility to future PhD students (their careers and the [other damage bad environments inflict](http://www.organizingcreativity.com/2014/08/responsibility-to-new-academic-hires/)).

There are guidelines for actual scientific misconduct (like plagiarism, fabrication, falsification), but is there anything for this kind of situation?

Comment: What does this situation have to do with critizing one's advisor?

Comment: You can run. Far far away. Now.

Comment: Re criticizing one's advisor — this person is part of the problem (and judging by other blogs, problems with advisers aren't rare). Thing is, if you criticize the institute, you also criticize the person who advised the thesis.

Comment: Re running away — yeah. My view is that if you are in a bad environment and cannot change it, get out as quickly as you can. But what is the responsibility to other PhD students here? After all, that institute is very good in presenting itself and attracting very good people.

Comment: I think your question is clear, but answers will consist mostly of opinions, so I won't vote to reopen. You're saying yourself that it might be a matter of personal preferences or fit. It's very unlikely that anyone here can give you the right answer. As a side note, what you described in your initial post didn't sound exceptional to me, I have heard about and seen many such academic hellholes.

Comment: @Cape Code Hmmm, it wasn't the only time I've encountered it either. I think these 'hellholes' are an issue that deserves attention, and I was hoping for some ideas on what to do in these cases — given that they aren't *that* rare.

Answer (score 9):

I see no ethical quandary whatsoever in revealing your own negative experience / suspicions of systemic problems within an academic department.  It would be easier to argue that some ethical obligation cuts in the other direction: i.e., 
people should be informed about what they're getting into.

You don't discuss your current status in the academic community. Of course complaining about people who are in a network of your peers and superiors could have some risk to you.  (That's basically always the case.)  But that's not an *ethical* concern.  The need to be "loyal" seems a bit misplaced here.  Yes, loyalty is good, but it cuts both ways.  Some people / an institution had a chance to treat you well, and apparently they really blew it.  They can't reasonably ask you to deny or minimize it.

I will say though that complaining is tricky.  The problem with people who are bitter enough to complain is that...well, they sound bitter.  In particular, your description of this nameless department sounds a bit cartoonishly bad to me: I couldn't recognize it in the context of any of the academic skullduggery I have seen in real life.  For one thing, you almost seem to be saying that the 
department faculty takes an active interest in crushing the dreams of students and postdocs.  To be honest, I am skeptical: crushing students' dreams can be hard work, and we are terribly busy.  For another, you imply that this department is viewed as exemplary and the terrible treatment and terrible placement of graduate students is totally ignored by your academic community.  Really?  In my circles (mathematics, US) departments are ranked in large part on how how well they service their graduate students: percentage of students who get through, time to degree, good placements.  Some places have a reputation for being "nicer" than others, but even a "not nice" top department does a better job of placing its students than a mediocre one.  Or so it seems to me, anyway.

So if you really want to complain effectively, I suggest you take the time to make your complaints factually based.  Can you assemble (in a solid, honest way) statistics to show that the department you talk about is bad for students?  People will take that a lot more seriously.

Comment: +1. If you follow the link, then this is actually 3rd party grieving: the snippet is what OP was told...and he reacted, apparently, not entirely dissimilarly from what you point out here ("maybe a bad fit?"). Hence, I don't think OP can elaborate. My hunch is that this was hyperbolic complaining to someone (OP) who wouldn't do that, but who takes others' words maybe a bit too much at face value.

Comment: Good points — and yep, the sounding bitter is a problem. And yeah, it was written in a hyperbolic way, among others, because it is also an emotional thing. I could have written it more neutral, but it would have missed some of the aspects of the problem. As for fact-based — having a look at the PhD students (attrition rates, tenure) is a way to evaluate institutes, something I'd recommend to all prospective PhD students. That would be a general recommendation. But what about making it more specific? (Can't put it better, still conflicted about the right course of action here.)